# Преобразовать строки в список

Tags: python, list

Привет, часть моего кода:

```
for r in pairs:
    d = (okex(r)['ticker']['buy'])
    print (d)
```

Вывод  данных такой:

```
0.00034262
0.00002440
0.00039001
0.11277453
0.00042372
```

Если запросить тип данных:

```
   print (type(d))
>>> <class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Требуется получить такой вывод:

```
[0.23424241, 0.52525021, 0.00243242]
```

Вроде довольно просто, но у меня или каждое число водружается в квадратные скобки, или вообще разбивается на символы по отдельности.

Comment: список float, чтобы проводить арифметические операции с другим списком,т.е., числами из другого списка

Comment: В  список float.

Comment: как можно одну строку в список преобразовать?

Comment: я так понимаю, что у меня много строк

Comment: @КириллВишняков, имеется в виду, можно одной строкой кода сделать то что вам нужно) Т.е. грубо говоря 2 варианта - чтобы было понятно и новичку, или как "правильно" одной строкой.

Comment: очень много дополнительных вопросов приходится создавать.. если я делаю: e=[]     e.append(d)    -    то каждую мою строку делают списком, а мне нужен список из чисел!

Comment: @КириллВишняков, `e=[] e.append(float(d))`

Comment: вот вывод: [0.0775964]
[0.00017332]
[4.87e-06]
[0.00279706]
[2.392e-05]

Comment: а как нужно, написано в вопросе

Comment: Пробовали. В таком случае мне печатает только самою последнюю строку. Наверно, нужен еще один цикл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта:

```
result = []
for r in pairs:
    d = okex(r)['ticker']['buy']
    result.append(float(d))

print(result)
```

Или одной строкой:

```
result = [float(okex(r)['ticker']['buy']) for r in pairs]
print(result)
```

Comment: Вы исправили ответ. До этого там был знак "+=" Что дает плюс перед равно?

Comment: Я не исправлял ответ, видимо вы до этого видели ответ другого участника (выше или ниже моего ответа). `+=` присоединяет к списку слева список справа. В данном случае достаточно `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Да соберите всё в список.

```
result = []
for r in pairs:
    d = (okex(r)['ticker']['buy'])
    result += [float(d)]

print(result)
```

Comment: Почему не одним циклом?

Comment: Судя по всему топикстартер начинающий - чтобы было понятно что происходит. В первом цикле складываются значения в список, ну а во втором приводятся к `float` и печатаются.

Comment: В любом случае не вижу особого смысла разбивать на два цикла. Можно было приведение в float сделать в первом же цикле.